# Is there any server load balancing benefit of processing events via JavaScript vs. Vaadin code?

Tags: java, optimization, vaadin

Say I want to process a button event that doesn't do any business logic, just updates the DOM:

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me");
button.addClickListener(evt -> button.setCaption("Clicked!"));
```

This does an event round-trip and adds strain to the server.

Now I can achieve the same with JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me");
button.setId("button");

JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(

              "$('#button').click(function(){"
            + "     $('#button').find('.v-button-caption').text('Clicked!');"
            + "})"
      );
```

Is this any kind of "server side" optimization?
 **Will the Vaadin client engine not send a request at all if no listeners are attached?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Button` there is no way around this (sending "button got clicked" to the server). Click listeners are are added at *runtime* on the server side.  So even if you add none, the client will inform the server about it (one could have been added in the meantime).

If you need this behaviour, you can achieve this by writing your own widget, that does that (e.g. GWT or `AbstractJavascriptComponent`).

As for your JQuery code there: the text change here will be lost (at best) once any state change from the server is applied or - in the worst case - will be a difference between client and server state. I would assume, that this kind of code is only useful to signal the user, that "this is processing right now, will take some time, so don't click again"

Comment: Also noticed it will not work if using `@PreserveOnRefresh`. Add it to your answer for commpleteness.

Answer (score 1):

Did not search this from documentation but tested in practice. I created a simple `UI` with only one button without adding any listeners. Clicking button resulted in a following kind of a request to the server

> 192.x.x.x - - [03/Jan/2018:09:56:20 +0200] "POST /vaadin-test/UIDL/?v-uiId=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 157

So whether listeners added or not **the request seems to be sent**. This suggests that there might not be a big optimization benefit when using the Vaadin `Button` component in a way you presented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an optimization technique. In client-server model and in computing in general, we try to stay away from I/O if possible and I/O is everything that is not CPU (including registers) and RAM. With the advent to fast SSDs, disk became way faster and it is the network that is usually the slowest part in any application that uses it.

Therefore avoiding network is an optimization technique. Why do you think caching is so prevalent in networked applications?

Comment: I think i didn't stress the last sentence strong enough. Does the client know that there are no listeners in the server and will not send a request? If the answer is no, then it's not worth the whole js roundabout.

Comment: I agree, I did not see that this was the main question. However, I did notice you saying: "This does an event round-trip and adds strain to the server." I don't think that this is the case - Vadin client side engine should not send a request for event listeners that are not performing actions server side (like initiating ajax onclick). The documentation states: "... although it is actually programmed in Java, which is compiled to JavaScript with the Vaadin Client Compiler." See: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/architecture/architecture-technology.html ... it is Javascript either way.